# Откуда качать Svn.NET?

Tags: svn

[Отсюда](http://pumacode.org/53/) не получаются, на странице не работает ни одной ссылки, а попытка скачать через svn по указанному адресу вылезает ошибка:

```
svn: E175002: Unable to connect to a repository at URL 'http://svn.pumacode.org/repos/svndotnet/trunk'

svn: E175002: OPTIONS of 'http://svn.pumacode.org/repos/svndotnet/trunk': Could

not resolve hostname `svn.pumacode.org': Затребованное имя допустимо и оно найдено в базе данных, но для имени отсутствуют связанные с ним данные, которые были разрешены для него.

 (http://svn.pumacode.org)
```

При попытке скачать с какого-то сайта, откуда можно скачать всё что угодно отругался антивирус.

Comment: Не оно? http://svn-net.apponic.com/download/link-1/

Comment: Это как раз то, на что ругается антивирус

Comment: Извините, а зачем вам потребовалась такая `outdated` штука на `Subversion 1.4?` Почему не [`SharpSvn?`](http://sharpsvn.open.collab.net/)

Answer (score 1):

Тогда возможно вот этот вариант поможет:

```
svn co https://pumaproject.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/pumaproject pumaproject
```

Comment: Нет, это плагин для Студии, а не библиотека.

Comment: Тогда возможно вот этот вариант поможет:

svn co https://pumaproject.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/pumaproject pumaproject

Comment: А как через Web-интерфейс скачать сразу папку?

Comment: А зачем вам через Web-интерфейс? Я вам команду дал, чтобы через SVN слить всё. Вы же ещё в вопросе указывали, что через SVN скачиваете исходники.